# yum install mysql-server.x86_64 - Transaction Check Errors

Tags: mysql, yum

I think `yum` is having problems installing MySQL 5.1 because there is already a pre-existing MySQL 5.5 installation.

I wanted to cleanly remove MySQL 5.5 (I had problems with 5.5 with PHP and Python).

I removed every folder and file associated with MySQL 5.5:

```
yum remove mysql-server
rm -i /usr/bin/mysq*
rm -R /var/lib/mysql/ /usr/share/mysql/ /usr/lib64/mysql/ /usr/include/mysql/
```

I type `find / -name mysql` and I get

```
/usr/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/mysql
/usr/lib64/perl5/DBD/mysql
```

Now when I try `yum install mysql-server.x86_64` I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * epel: mirror.hiwaay.net
 * extras: centos.digitalcompass.net
 * updates: centos.digitalcompass.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.61-1.el6_2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.1.61-1.el6_2.1 for package: mysql-server-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.61-1.el6_2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs = 5.1.61-1.el6_2.1 for package: mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.52-1.el6_0.1 will be updated
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.61-1.el6_2.1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                             Arch                                                          Version                                                                 Repository                                                      Size
================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-server                                                        x86_64                                                        5.1.61-1.el6_2.1                                                        updates                                                        8.1 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql                                                               x86_64                                                        5.1.61-1.el6_2.1                                                        updates                                                        881 k
Updating for dependencies:
 mysql-libs                                                          x86_64                                                        5.1.61-1.el6_2.1                                                        updates                                                        1.2 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total size: 10 M
Total download size: 9.0 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 881 kB     00:00     
(2/2): mysql-server-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                          | 8.1 MB     00:02     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3.0 MB/s | 9.0 MB     00:02     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/mysql from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/msql2mysql from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql_find_rows from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql_waitpid from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlaccess from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqladmin from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlbinlog from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlcheck from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqldump from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlimport from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlshow from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlslap from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlslap.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/msql2mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-server-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlbinlog.1.gz from install of mysql-server-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz from install of mysql-server-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlimport.1.gz from install of mysql-server-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql_config from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-devel-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-devel-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I removed every file and folder named `mysql`, do I need to remove this `MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64` packages? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to remove the MySQL 5.5 client, to remove the conflicts.  Try

```
rpm -e MySQL-client-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
rpm -e MySQL-devel-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 4):

Double check that the mysql packages have been completely removed

```
yum list installed | grep -i mysql
```

if anything is found, remove with

```
yum erase <package-name>
```

if there are NO packages left installed. The list of directories that were output as conflicting reference all the files that remain, and therefore... Must be removed!

EDIT: And yes, remove the MySQL-client package. That does actually appear to be the conflict.

Comment: This worked great for resolving my yum conflicts. Thanks!